# Проблема с отоброжением русских символов

Tags: java, строки, кодировка

Работаю в NeatBeans

Когда я присваиваю переменной типа String значение на русском, в окне вывода вместо этого значения показывают знаки вопроса:

```
ввод: русс
вывод: ????
```

Я изменял кодировку с UTF-8 на windows-1251,но ничего не поменялось

вот код

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("ввод ");
String s1 = input.nextLine(); 
System.out.print("\nВывод "+s1);
```

**UPD:** Решение проблемы есть(надо что-то изменять в настройках), но я его не помню. Намного лучшее решение - переход на IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы строковые литералы выводились в консоль правильно, при комплиляции укажите кодировку файла исходного кода `javac -encoding utf-8 Main.java`.

Ввод\вывод с консолью под Windows вопрос не простой, так как стандартная кодировка операционной системы - cp1251, а кодировка консоли - cp866. Поэтому надо считать строку в одной кодировке, а вывести в другой:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String args[]) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.print("ввод ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in, "Windows-1251"); //Считываем в кодировке операционной системы
        String s1 = input.nextLine(); 
        String encoded = new String(s1.getBytes("windows-1251"), Charset.forName("cp866")); //Преобразуем в кодировку консоли
        System.out.println("\nВывод " + encoded);
    }
}
```